# How do I remove the items which already are in the target of a picklist?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, picklist

On my page I have a picklist which the user can set of `profiles` for a `system`, those are my entities, but when the user wants to add or remove those properties I use the same picklist and the selected `properties` must be shown on the `target` and not on the `source`.

My question is:

How do I remove the items which already are in the `target`? 
I've used an iterator on both `source` and the `target` from the `dao` and removed the items from the `source` but I´m not that sure if it is the best option or if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you want to remove itens from target, you should just remove from the target list in backbean and update the component. Remember to warn the user with a message or something else that some of the itens that he picked is not there anymore. For me this is the solution, I don't know if there is an "elegant" solution

Comment: I think you're right; I just asked it in order to not re-do a job that the component could be providing. Anyways, thanks for helping me out.